# Stale ref value in useState set function

Tags: reactjs

Imagine a typical react todo app when user can add a todo based on text input and add it to the list of todos.
Let's say that in order to clear inputs value after adding a todo I'm using ref on the input. What happens is that inside useStates updater function (setTodos in this case) `inputRef.current.value` is empty (apart from the first invocation). Does anyone know why is this the case?

Code:

```
function App() {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const addTodo = () => {
    console.log(inputRef.current.value); // This will log the current value

    setTodos((todos) => {
      console.log(inputRef.current.value); // This will log empty value after 2nd call
      return [...todos, inputRef.current.value];
    });
    inputRef.current.value = "";
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label>
        Add todo
        <input placeholder="Add todo" ref={inputRef} />
        <button onClick={addTodo}>Add</button>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Please note that I know how to fix this, I am looking for answer why does it work this way.

Comment: The ```setState``` callback does not execute immediately. It might execute after you reset the value  ```inputRef.current.value = ""```, this is why you see empty value. But not sure why this happens only after the second call